# How do you configure a DotNet Core 3.0 app to take HTTPS requests fron a NGINX and Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, https, configuration, .net-core-3.0

I am having trouble setting an application up. I am using Docker for all of the containers. I have one container that takes request from the host where my NGINX proxy server runs. I am using NGINX as my edge server and it handles the HTTP -> HTTPS switchover and cert management (I am using a wildcard cert if that matters). Then it hits the main app at Location "/". The main app is in a separate container and is running DotNet Core 3.0. They are both on the same docker network. My issue is with connecting the 2 in a secure manner. I first tried to configure Kestrel using the same cert but had issues there, possibly followed the docs wrong. I decided to scrap that and try it without Kestrel since NGINX is technically the edge server but I am getting issues with the HTTPS coming from NGINX and getting rejected by the app, things like insecure connection or no cert found. All of the info I have found has bits and pieces of what I need and I feel I am missing a small piece to make this work. What is the right way to configure the secure connection between the app and proxy and how do I get static IP/Ports so that I can connect them?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more reading of the docs it looks like my original approach was the best way to go. See, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configuration. The recommendation is to run Kestrel with the

Since I am running the app behind a reverse proxy, across separate IP addresses, this becomes a cross origin situation on the same domain. So the solution is to configure Kestrel to use HTTPS using the wildcard certificate that the edge server uses. This should achieve best practice, end to end encryption from client to app.